# Best way to store a huge list of Objects to disk in java

Tags: java, serialization

This is the object which I'm planning to store in disk,

```
public class SObject {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private String value;
    private int occurences;
    private String key;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getOccurences() {
        return occurences;
    }

    public void setOccurences(int occurences) {
        this.occurences = occurences;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

I am thinking of creating a list of objects and Store that list to a new class like below,

```
public class ToDisk implements Serializable{
        List<SObject> sobj;

    public List<SObject> getSobj() {
        return sobj;
    }

    public void setSobj(List<SObject> sobj) {
        this.sobj = sobj;
    }

}
```

Is this an efficient way with minimal code work to write data? I also find it easier to read the data from the disk by using serialization. Because the size of list could be very high (~10k+), and I should find a balance between ease of code and size. Is there any way to achieve this balance? Please let me know if there are any other methods to store data in a reduced size compared to serialization. I cannot use any external libraries.

Comment: You don't *need* to use the list; you can serialize multiple objects to a single file and read them back in the same order.

Comment: Are you sure that what you really need is not a simple database?

Comment: @Deadron I cannot/should not use a db, just a simple file write.

Comment: Look up disk based collections

Comment: I could only find external libraries, I cannot use any external libraries.

Comment: @arshajii Does that give any significant advantage in size/speed?

Comment: @Naren I believe it would, since serializing the list would store unnecessary fields and attributes of the `List` instance, which would then have to be read back as well. Whether the difference will be "significant" is open for debate.

Comment: Converting one object at a time might also be better in term of memory performance. Imagine a object containing ~10K objects and then serializing them into one big String in memory and then writing that big String into file. Might cause memory issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BTW You don't need a list wrapper to write many items to a file, but your items so need to be Serializable.

```
public class SObject {
    private String value;
    private int occurences;
    private String key;
}
```

to write

```
List<SObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
oos.writeObject(list);
oos.close();
```

to read

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
List<SObject> list = (List<SObject>) ois.readObject(); // cast is needed.
ois.close()
```

to write compressed

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new DeflaterOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
oos.writeObject(list);
oos.close();
```

to read compressed

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new InflaterInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
List<SObject> list = (List<SObject>) ois.readObject(); // cast is needed.
ois.close()
```

---

> Is this an efficient way with minimal code work to write data?

You have to make SObject `implement Serializable` and that is all. You can't make it shorter.

You can make it more efficient by making it `implement Externalizable` but this is more work.

> I also find it easier to read the data from the disk by using serialization.

Sounds like a good reason to do it.

> Because the size of list could be very high (~10k+),

10K sounds small to me unless your strings are really long.  I have a test for my serialization/peristsence library and it writes and reads 10,000,000 entries in seconds.

> I should find a balance between ease of code and size. Is there any way to achieve this balance?

I suspect ease is all you need worry about. If youw ant to make the file smaller you can compress it by wrapping the file stream with GZIP or deflator/inflator stream.  This adds a line of code and can make the file 4x smaller.

> Please let me know if there are any other methods to store data in a reduced size compared to serialization. I cannot use any external libraries.

They all require external libraries.  You can use XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder, but this will be slower and bigger.

---

Since I got a question on it; If you are interested in my library [Java Chronicle 2.x](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Chronicle) Here is a result from a test running on my laptop. This time how long it took to write 500 million entries and read them in a second thread (as they were being written) It took just over 12 seconds.

```
Rate = 41.0 Mmsg/sec for 16 byte messages
```

The test is multiThreaded() in [IndexedChronicleTest](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Chronicle/blob/master/chronicle/src/test/java/net/openhft/chronicle/IndexedChronicleTest.java)

Comment: *I have a test for my serialization/peristsence library* - which library is that?

Comment: @Jitendra It is Java Chronicle, I have tests which show writing 40 million messages per second on a laptop and messages being read in another process with a latency of 0.6 micro-seconds.  https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle is the older version and https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Chronicle is the faster, new and improved version.

Comment: System.out.println(objList.size()); // size is printed
  try {
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
     new FileOutputStream("\\users\\naren\\folder\\test.txt"));
   oos.writeObject(objList);
   oos.close();} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } // no error is thrown but i could not see the file. am I missing something?

Comment: If you are running this on linux you need to look for a file called `\users\naren\folder\test.txt`, note \ is just a character on Linux. Perhaps you intended `/users/naren/folder/test.txt` and perhaps a different extension as this is not text.

Answer (score 0):

Best way will probably be to Serialize the `ArrayList` to disk.

Make sure that the contents of the list are serializable, i.e., the objects in the list should implement the `Serializable` interface.

then
**to write to file:**

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
oos.writeObject(list);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

**To read from file:**

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
List<YourClass> list = ois.readObject();
ois.close()
```

Comment: The flush() is redundant.